# Running a loop to check for multiple congruences

Tags: number-theory, procedural-programming

I have the code for a loop to run. Right now it can check if a number is a square and at the same time check if it is congruent 0 mod 47. My questions is, how can I alter the code to see if it is congruent for more than one prime. SO for instance I would like it to check that a number is congruent, 0 mod 5, 0 mod 13 and 0 mod 17 all at once and only keep or print the numbers which are. I would try something like:
'Select[Range[10^7]^2, Divisible[7 # + 4, 5], Divisible[7 # + 4, 13], Divisible[7 # + 4, 17] &]'
but it just prints numbers most of which I am assuming do not satisfy the desired effect

Comment: `Select[Range[10^5]^2, 
 Divisible[#, 5] && Divisible[#, 13] && Divisible[#, 17] &]`?

Comment: also I would really like to be able to check whether (4^n)-1 is congruent 0 mod5 0 mod 13 and 0 mod 17 not for 7n+4

Comment: thank you @HenrikSchumacher, I actually do not care if the number is a perfect square rather it must have the form (4^n)-1. I apologize for my ignorance but your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem here. You already found that you may use `Select`. The only thing you did wrong is not to use `And` (`&&`). The selection function is required to produce either `True` or `False`. And, of course, you may use any list you like as first argument of `Select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find solutions, for example, the code:

```
FindInstance[{n == a^2, 7 n + 4 == m, m == 5 b}, {n, m, a, b}, Integers]
```

returns `{}` to indicate no solutions. The alternative code

```
Reduce[{n == a^2, 7 n + 4 == m, m == 5 b}, {m}, Integers]
```

returns `False` similarly. Try variations of these codes depending on your needs.

However, both `Reduce[]` and `FindInstance[]` are not good with exponential equations.

For that, you can use some code

```
Select[2^Range[0, 20] - 1, Divisible[#, 5] && Divisible[#, 13] &]
```

which returns `{0, 4095}` and you can try variations of this.

Comment: Thank you, I just want to adjust it so that it does it for numbers of the form (4^n)-1 so I tried the following code and it does nothing:

Comment: Select[Table[Divisible[(4^i)-1,5] && Divisible [(4^i)-1, 13] && Divisible[(4^i)-1,17] {i,200} &]

Comment: That is helpful but how could I use that to check for it being divisible by 5 and 13 and 17 at the same time or if I change the base 4 to 3 lets say?

Comment: I tried adjusting the base and it tells me that everything is zero:

Comment: {In[3]:= FindInstance[{2^i-1 == n, n == 5 a}, {i, a, n}, Integers]

Out[3]= {{i -> 0, a -> 0, n -> 0}}

Answer (score 2):

For the question, expressed in a comment by argamon, of finding numbers of the form (4^n)-1 congruent to 0 mod 5, 0 mod 13, and 0 mod 17, please consider the function `ChineseRemainder`.

```
Block[{c},
   Flatten[Table[
      c = ChineseRemainder[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 13, 17}, m];
      If[c == m, m, {}],
      {m, Table[4^k - 1, {k, 1, 50}]}]]
]
```

> {16777215, 281474976710655, 4722366482869645213695,
>   79228162514264337593543950335}